# How to link html login page to another

Tags: javascript, css, html

I  have created simple login page using html. i want create link with another page after click login page.here attach my code i set  its not working .how to link another page after login ..here My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>    
  <body>
<IMG class="displayed" src="images/wel..png" alt="...">

<div id="login">
  <div id="triangle"></div>
  <h1>Log in</h1>
  <form>        
    <input type="Username" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />        
    <input  type="submit" value="Log in" />    
  </form>
</div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your form action? No action on the from?

Comment: http://www.javatpoint.com/login-form-in-jsp
Since you are using jsp I am suggesting the above link..

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for action attribute of form?
Try this:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com" method="post">
    <input type="Username" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input  type="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>
```

Comment: Happy to hear it helps you! :)
Make it as resolve! ;)

Answer (score 0):

you have to change

```
<form action="youpagename">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to following:

```
<form method="GET" action="foo.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

This is the same, but valid, and is equivalent to:

```
<a href="foo.html">
```